# Xpath / Find all attributes which start with specific pattern

Tags: xpath

I want to find all the elements which there **attributes** start with `x`.

For example,

```
<a xt="1"> text1 </a>
<a xu="2"> text2 </a>
<a text1="3"> text3 </a>
```

The xpath would find the first two elements, because it contains attributes with it name is `xt` and `xu`, respectively. `text1` attribute doesn't start with `x`, and for that I will not get it.

I try with `start-with()` function, but as I understood it find the values, and not attributes.

Comment: Is it Xpath 1.0 or 2.0? In 2.0 you can use regular expressions.

Comment: I use WebDriver, find by xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(local-name(),'x')]]
```

Similar to the other answer, but uses `local-name()` instead. This will only check the attribute name and not the namespace prefix.

For example, if you use `local-name()` the following will also be matched because the prefix starts with `x`...

```
<a xns:text1="3" xmlns:xns="xns"> text3 </a>
```

If you use `local-name()`, it will not match because the local name of `xns:text1` is `text1`.

Comment: i agree, but the OP did not mention any namespace.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen - The OP didn't mention namespaces, but with a question this basic I doubt the OP realizes the difference. I was just pointing out the differences so there wasn't any confusion in real world usage.

Comment: Yup, as I said, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
@*[starts-with(name(), 'x')]
```